# Is there a way to pre-process data using the Joi validation package?

Tags: javascript, joi

Is there a way that you can provide some sort of function to a Joi validation schema that will pre-process the value before it gets validated by Joi rules? For example, if a  user inputs a date in some arbitrary format, can I call some processing function that formats the input prior to undergoing Joi validation?

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  "date": Joi.someFunc((originalValue) => {
    return convertToSomeFormat(originalValue);
  }).date(),
});
```

Comment: That wouldn't make a lot of sense? If a user providers dates in a weird format, your client-side code should have fixed that at the time of submission, so that the submission payload (or API call, etc) can be validated without any sort of rewriting. If your users are supposed to pick dates, give them a date picker that you control the resultant string format for. Don't let them make up some format themselves.